# Create package with all gem dependencies

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I need to install some gems (with additional dependencies) on a system which has no Internet accees.

Is it possible to create a package which has all required dependencies pre-installed? So that I can use "gem install package".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bundler package` is a tool just for that:
https://bundler.io/man/bundle-package.1.html

> Copy all of the `.gem` files needed to run the application into the `vendor/cache` directory. In the future, when running `bundle install`, use the gems in the cache in preference to the ones on `rubygems.org`.